# Scala - Heroku - Play!: cannot resolve symbol ReverseApplication

Tags: java, scala, heroku, deployment

I'm trying to deploy a `Play` application written in `Scala` on `Heroku` following [this documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ProductionHeroku). On my local machine everything works fine, the server starts correctly and there's no error at compile time, when deploying on `Heroku` I get this errors:

> [error] /tmp/scala_buildpack_build_dir/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/com/my/project/application/action/routes.java:8: cannot find symbol
>
> [error] symbol  : class ReverseApplication
>
> [error] location: package com.my.project.application.action
>
> [error] public static final com.my.project.application.action.ReverseApplication Application = new com.my.project.application.action.ReverseApplication();

And other very similar regarding a `ref` package (which I don't have in my project) like this one:

> package com.my.project.application.action.ref does not exist

Then I went looking for what was generated by the `sbt clean compile stage` command and I found this (`routes.class`):

```
package com.my.project.application.job;

public class routes {
  
  public static final com.my.project.application.job.ReverseApplication Application = new com.my.project.application.job.ReverseApplication();

  public static class javascript {
    public static final com.my.project.application.job.javascript.ReverseApplication Application = new com.my.project.application.job.javascript.ReverseApplication();
  }

  public static class ref {
    public static final com.my.project.application.job.ref.ReverseApplication Application = new com.my.project.application.job.ref.ReverseApplication();
  }
}
```

Where `javascript.ReverseApplication` and `ref.ReverseApplication` cannot be found, there's another generated file called `routes_reverseRouting.scala` which has this missing packages but it's not imported in the `routes.class` when compiling and staging. Am I missing something? Last time I deployed (a week ago or so) I didn't had this problems.

I'm using `scala v2.10.3` and `sbt v13.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that `Heroku` doesn't clean up the build if you don't explicitly configure it using `heroku config:set SBT_CLEAN=true` as described [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scala-support#clean-builds).